# PHP Optimization: Integer instead of float

Tags: php, optimization, floating-point, int, precision

I have a PHP script that have a lot of calculations, loops e.t.c.
So I have to optimize the code, because one AJAX request takes a lot of time (for example 20sec). 
When I look at the "echo" text (encoded with json_encode) I see that the numbers have 12 decimal digits. I don't need this precision. I need integers (or max. 3 decimal digits). 
Can I decrease the precision of calculations to have better request time?

Sorry for my english ;)

Comment: _decrease the precision of calculations to have better request time?..._ You are talking about below micro seconds... and if you need integers you can use round() etc

Comment: Do you have any database/file access, they will be the first things to look at.

Comment: You're far more likely to gain time somewhere else in your code. Are you making any db connections/queries? Unless you're performing some exceedingly complex calculations, they are unlikely to be what's slowing you down.

Comment: I know, that there are only microseconds. But some of my functions are called few thousend times. There is no db connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut down all your numbers which you are sending then you can use `array_map` and `bcdiv` to cut down the precision.

However, using `array_map` will take a linear amount of time to complete, so you are better off inserting your data into the array you are going to send in the `bcdiv` format:

```
$data = [0.123214, 1.21321424, 0.312321, 3.213213123]; // Lets say this is the data you are sending
$small = array_map(function($num) {
    return bcdiv($num, 1, 3); // Cut the decimal to 3 places
}, $data);

print_r($small);
```

**Output**:

`Array ( [0] => 0.123 [1] => 1.213 [2] => 0.312 [3] => 3.213 )`

Comment: If this is done _after_ the calculation of the numbers, it's just going to add even more processing.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that's why I suggest that OP doesn't use array_map and instead enters the data into the array using the shortened numbers :) - via`bcdiv`, I'll make that clearer though

Answer (score 0):

For any interpreted language (such as PHP), the speed of individual operations does not make nearly as much difference as the *number of* operations.

On modern computers, floating point operations are only slightly slower than fixed point.  Meanwhile, the interpreter's overhead of finding and fiddling with a variable takes dozens of times as long as the actual operation.

If, for integers, you need to *add* something like `round()` to the number of operations, adding it may cost more than any savings in the actual fixed vs float CPU instructions.

You mentioned passing numbers around.  The network cost of sending more bytes (for more decimal places) is also a factor.

Here are some numbers.  Caveat:  They are probably significantly 'off'.  But it gives you some way to compare things.  All are in nanoseconds.

```
0.5 Integer add
1.0 double precision add (16 significant digits)
30 PHP overhead for either add
30 PHP time to perform virtually any simple action
200 the time to send one more byte across to/from a remote site
```

But, you need to also count the frequency of them...

If you are doing matrix arithmetic, then there may be thousands or millions of arithmetic operations.  In this case, you are looking at 30ns * some big number.  That would be a big number.

If you are sending an extra 5 bytes via AJAX that would be so small as to be not measurable.

To look at it yet another way:

- By fiddling with the "low level" things (eg, int vs float), you might improve the speed by a few percent.
- By finding a better algorithm, you might speed up the program by an "order of magnitude".

Lesson:  Focus on the big picture; there's more bang for the buck there.